# Angular Error while querying data on show hide on Search using DOM

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dom

I'm trying to do search queries. I want to show and hide data on keyup Event Listner. This code works fine on some devices but not working on safari and some other devices.

Please help me.

```
let bol = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('searchInputIdSeasPg')).value;

if (bol.length > 0) {
  document.getElementById('tobotiSearch').style.display = 'grid';
  const x = document.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>(".cont");
  x.forEach((cod) => {
    const shouldShow = cod.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(bol) > -1;
    cod.style.display = shouldShow ? 'block' : 'none';
  });
```

Comment: If this is indeed Angular, I’d try to solve this the Angular way.

Comment: Thank you. please help me with this error

Comment: Is there an actual error on those devices?

Comment: No there's no error